# Prevent Intellisense from inserting semicolons in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

We don't use semicolons in TypeScript. Each time Intellisense in VS code (v1.18.1) inserts a line, it terminates it with `;`. Example would be an import statement.

Is it possible to configure VS Code not to append semicolons? Very inefficient right now to have to delete them manually.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499995/how-to-disable-automatic-semicolon-at-end-line-with-typescript-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 13):

[TSLint semicolon rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon/) (has autofix)

[TSLint extension for vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin)

`tslint.json` rules section:

```json
"semicolon": [true, "never"]
```

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"tslint.autoFixOnSave": ["semicolon"]
```

---

There is an open issue about it https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19882

Comment: Thanks. I've done that, but added `"tslint.autoFixOnSave": ["semicolon"]` to the `settings.json` as I am not sure I want all other rules auto corrected on save. This is perhaps the best workaround at the moment. I have asked VS Code team for a config option to make use of trailing `;` optional in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39802

Comment: Looks like `tslint.autoFixOnSave` option is deprecated now. The current combination that sort of gives me what I need is `"editor.codeActionsOnSave":  {    "source.deleteSemicolons": true }, "editor.formatOnSave": true, ...`. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49223#issuecomment-387146776

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Prettier add to settings.json
"prettier.semi": false

And then in tslint.json
"semicolon": [true, "never"],

Comment: Thanks. This is the workaround I've been using so far. Hopefully, VS Code will start honoring this setting soon.

Answer (score 0):

[TypeScript 3.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-6/) is now able to detect whether your file uses semicolons or not, which can be leveraged in VS Code for quick fixes, refactorings, transformations (e.g. auto import) and other features. It is called [Semicolon-Aware Code Edits](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-6/#semicolon-aware-code-edits).

> Editors like Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code can automatically apply quick fixes, refactorings, and other transformations like automatically importing values from other modules. These transformations are powered by TypeScript, and older versions of TypeScript unconditionally added semicolons to the end of every statement; unfortunately, this disagreed with many users’ style guidelines, and many users were displeased with the editor inserting semicolons.
>
> TypeScript is now smart enough to detect whether your file uses semicolons when applying these sorts of edits. If your file generally lacks semicolons, TypeScript won’t add one.